# How to set TTL to a particular field while updating it in Solr documents

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

A Solr document, let's say, has the schema that includes `id` and `score`. For every `id` I am updating a score based on an event trigger. However I want the score to become 0 or maybe gradually reduce after a week or so. Basically I need to set a TTL of about a week to that `score` field. Or I need the value of the `score` to be time-dependent somehow.

I am not setting TTL to the document because I want to retain the `id` but not the `score`, after a week. How can this be achieved??

I browsed a lot over internet, couldn't find the solution. That is why turned to the experts here in stack overflow.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

The TTL is useful to automatically delete the doc after the TTL is reached, not to modify one field.

What you want to do is boost documents by time field, as explained [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents). The trick is `recip` function. You could further modify the expression to make the boost 0 when it's older than a week etc.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q={!boost b=recip(ms(NOW,manufacturedate_dt),3.16e-11,1,1)}ipod
```